# Google Sheets to transform a table into a nested tree output or hierarchical structure output

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I just wonder if there is an easy way to transform the *Google Sheets* **Original Input** cells into a more readable table as in **Output A** or even **Output B**?

| **Original Input** |  |  | **Output A** |  |  | **Output B** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Group** | **Points** |  | **Group** | **Points** |  | **Points** |
| A | BBBB |  | A |  |  | A |
| A | CCCC |  |  | BBBB |  | - BBBB |
| A | DDDD |  |  | CCCC |  | - CCCC |
| A | EEEE |  |  | DDDD |  | - DDDD |
| B | FFFF |  |  | EEEE |  | - EEEE |
| B | GGGG |  | B |  |  | B |
| B | HHHH |  |  | FFFF |  | - FFFF |
|  |  |  |  | GGGG |  | - GGGG |
|  |  |  |  | HHHH |  | - HHHH |

[image: The three tables in a Google Sheets file.]

I know I can do it with *App Script* but I am curious if there are some smart solutions like a combo of query/filter/sort without the need for the *App Script* solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach (for your preferred arrangement, given that the non-header data runs in A3:B):

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(QUERY({VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A,A3:A<>""))&"*",{A3:A,ROW(A3:A)&"-"&COLUMN(A3:A)},{1,2},FALSE);FILTER({"|"&B3:B,ROW(B3:B)&"-"&COLUMN(B3:B)},A3:A<>"")},"Select Col1 ORDER BY Col2"),"|",1,0))`

**ADDENDUM** (based on additional comment from poster):

This version of the formula will work on unsorted raw data:

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(QUERY({VLOOKUP(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A,A3:A<>"")))&"*",{SORT(FILTER(A3:A,A3:A<>"")),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A3:A),1)&"-"&COLUMN(A1)},{1,2},FALSE);SORT(FILTER("|"&B3:B,A3:A<>""),1,1,2,1),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A3:A),1)&"-"&COLUMN(B1)},"Select Col1 ORDER BY Col2"),"|",1,0))`

Comment: Thanks. All 3 replied formula works but the other two work only with unique records because they select max(Col2) for the content. Your formula works without such assumption. However, it does not work when the records are out of order. I think we can probably use sort() before filtering or query will work better.

Comment: Always keep in mind that we only know what you show and tell us. Your post example data showed everything already sorted A-Z. Please see the addendum on my post for a version of the formula that will work with unsorted raw data.

Answer (score 2):

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(QUERY({A3:A&"×", "¤"&B3:B&"×", B3:B}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),, 9^9)),,9^9), "×")), "¤")))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution. It works with unique emails. I think it's because we are using max(Col2) within the query. But it still works under the condition set out in the question.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(QUERY({A3:A&"×", "- "&B3:B&"×", B3:B}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),, 9^9)),,9^9), "×"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution again. It works under the conditions in my original question. It does not work if there are duplicated emails and when the entry out of orders. I think you can fix it easily. The solution is inspiring!